# SwiftUI: Display content conditional on fitting

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building an application in SwiftUI. I have trouble supporting smaller screen sizes. Is there some way (some View modifier for example) to display View's on the condition that they fit the screen.

Comment: How about [```ViewThatFits```](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits)?

Comment: You may also read here [UserInterfaceSizeClass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/userinterfacesizeclass) and [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader), and also work out some introduction tutorials. Please refine your question with some sample code.